# Python ElementTree : partially parsing a large file

Tags: python, performance, parsing, partial, elementtree

I have a large XML file, which is roughly structured (in this order) :

```
<document>
   <interesting_part>
     ...
   </interesting_part>
   <foo>
     ...
     60000 lines
     ...
   </foo>
</document>
```

My program is :

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
f=open(path_f)
tree=et.parse(f)
f.close()
# retreive infos from tree...
```

Only the first few block interests me in the file, but performance is low because et.parse() loads the whole file.

How to load the file only till < / interesting_part > ?

I thought of something like :

```
class My_Parser(et.XMLParser):
    ????
my_parser = My_Parser()
tree=et.parse(f, my_parser)
```

Thanking you by advance,
Eric.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`iterparse()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) instead, and simply stop iterating when you have what you want:

```
for event, element in et.iterparse(f):
    if element.tag == 'interesting_part':
        # `element` is the complete <interesting_part> element, with children
        # process it
        break  # ends parsing.
```